# Increment file name TCL

Tags: file-io, tcl, filenames

My input file has 5 lines and all 5 lines are printed into 1 file. How can I print each line in one file during puts? How can I increment an existing filename?

```
# Input file
1 2 3 4
1 3 4 5
2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4
```

```
set infile  [open "infile.txt" r]
set outfile [open "outfile.txt" w]
set count    0

     while {[gets $infile line] > 0} {
        incr count

          puts $outfile"$count" "I want to split the input file into 4 different files. Each file is one line"      
    }
```

Seems like TCL does not like the above syntax? I am hoping to get outfile1, outfile2.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
set outfile [open "outfile.txt" w]
```

A file handle, `outfile` is created associated with 'outfile.txt', opened for writing.  This file handle will stay associated with the opened file until it
is closed.   If you want output to a different file, you must open that other
file and assign the file handle to a variable.

For the purposes of your question, you would need to open the output file 
within the `while` loop.

Comment: Agree. Alse, use "outfile$count" instead of $outfile"$count". And don't forget to close the file at the end because otherwise the created files may be empty.

Answer (score 3):

If you intend to write to different files, the file names should be different. So that's where the `$count` is going to go. In your current code, `$outfile` is not the file, but a [channel identifier](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm#M4) to the file.

For example, something you could do is:

```
set infile  [open "infile.txt" r]

set count    0

while {[gets $infile line] > 0} {
    incr count

    set outfile [open "outfile$count.txt" w]
    puts $outfile $line
    close $outfile
}

close $infile
```

Which would create files `outfile1.txt` .. `outfile5.txt`.